# How to determine a function that satisfies the following:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question is to determine a function which will later help me answer this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364100/derive-an-equation-in-n-for-the-mean-of-the-products-of-all-distinct-pairs-of-po):

Given this set of points, how do I determine an equation which satisfies them:

**n          $Y$**

$3$         $1$

$4$         $1$

$5$         $2$

$6$         $2$

$7$         $3$

$8$         $3$

..............

One candidate I developed was:

$\lfloor \dfrac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$

However, I would prefer to be able to determine something that doesn't depend on a floor (an equation straight in $n$).

Any hints on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: You numbers looks like a straight line with periodic bumps with period 2. A natural guess is some linear combination of $n$ and $(-1)^n$. By trial and error, it is easy to discover $\frac{2n - 3 -(-1)^n}{4}$ fit the data.

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is an excellent one.  To avoid the floor, you can put a fifth degree polynomial through the points.  You can see the interpolated function at [this Alpha page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate%20polynomial&f1=%7B1,1,2,2,3,3%7D&x=5&y=4&f=InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data_%7B1,1,2,2,3,3%7D&a=%2aFVarOpt.1-_%2a%2a%2aInterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data--.%2a%2a%2aInterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data2---.%2a--)  It is shifted horizontally by $3$ units, but the shape is correct.
I think it is a *far* worse description of the data.  Alternately, you might put a straight line through the midpoints of the horizontal segments:  Y=$\frac 12 n - \frac 54$  It's not far from the points and is very simple.